# Как сделать последовательное выполнение команд в bat файле?

Tags: bat, atom

Пытаюсь написать bat файл, для установки всех модулей приложения Atom:

```
@echo off
apm install atom-beautify
apm install atom-runner
apm install color-picker
pause
```

,но после запуска выполняется только 1 команда, и командная строка тут же закрывается.
Как сделать установку последовательной, чтобы весь процесс выводился в консоль?

Answer (score 1):

Если вызываемый скрипт может закрывать консоль, то стоит его запускать в другой консоли явно. В таком случае если он её закроет, текущая продолжит работать. А если не закроет, то она всё равно закроется сама после выполнения команды.

```
@echo off
cmd /c apm install atom-beautify
cmd /c apm install atom-runner
cmd /c apm install color-picker
pause
```

Comment: Ваш код тоже срабатывает. Проверил.

Answer (score 0):

Символ & существует для разделения нескольких команд в одной командной строке. Выполняется первая команда, затем вторая команда.
Символ ^ означает, что следующая строка является продолжением текущей.

```
@echo off
apm install atom-beautify &^
apm install atom-runner &^
apm install color-picker &^
pause
```

по сути получается как-то так:

```
@echo off
apm install atom-beautify & apm install atom-runner & apm install color-picker & pause
```

Comment: Этот код будет вести себя точно так же, как код из вопроса.

Comment: поверьте, не точно так же...

Comment: тут дело не в bat а в apm... После выполнения 1 команды он закрывает окно.

Comment: Решается с помощью `cmd /c apm ...`. А этот код такой же.

Comment: @Qwertiy, попробуйте сами. У меня Windows 11. После попытки вызвать первый код он закрывается после выполнения atom-beautify, во втором же случае все работает.